# How do I filter media by include and excluded tags using the Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models...

```
class Media(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Filter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tags_included = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True, related_name='included_tags')
    tags_excluded = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True, related_name='excluded_tags')

    def get_media(self):
        return """ return all media that has any tags_included set and remove all media that has tags_excluded set """
```

And I am looking for a method of getting a media selection based on a filter of tags that must be included and tags that must not be included. So I guess it must use __in, filter and exclude some how but cant seem to get anything to run.

Any help with this would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're almost there. This should work:

```py
class Filter(models.Model):
    ...

    def get_media(self):
        return Media.objects.filter(
            tags__in=self.tags_included.all()
        ).exclude(
            tags__in=self.tags_excluded.all()
        )
```

I'm not sure what version of Django you're using, but I tested the following with 2.2 and 3.3:

```py
>>> from media.models import Media, Tag, Filter
>>> 
>>> red = Tag.objects.create(name='red')
>>> green = Tag.objects.create(name='green')
>>> blue = Tag.objects.create(name='blue')
>>> 
>>> purple_media = Media.objects.create(name='purple')
>>> teal_media = Media.objects.create(name='teal')
>>> brown_media = Media.objects.create(name='brown')
>>> 
>>> purple_media.tags.add(blue, red)
>>> teal_media.tags.add(green, blue)
>>> brown_media.tags.add(green, red)
>>> 
>>> def filter_media(_filter):
...     return Media.objects.filter(
...         tags__in=_filter.tags_included.all()
...     ).exclude(
...         tags__in=_filter.tags_excluded.all()
...     )   
... 
>>> blue_filter = Filter.objects.create(name='include blue')
>>> blue_filter.tags_included.add(blue)
>>> filter_media(blue_filter).values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 7, 'name': 'purple'}, {'id': 8, 'name': 'teal'}]>
>>> 
>>> blue_but_not_red_filter = Filter.objects.create(name='blue but not red')
>>> blue_but_not_red_filter.tags_included.add(blue)
>>> blue_but_not_red_filter.tags_excluded.add(red)
>>> filter_media(blue_but_not_red_filter).values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 8, 'name': 'teal'}]>
```